# Insert data into database using HibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate, dao

I'm beginner at hibernate and spring framework. I want to insert into database using hibernate template. My DAO code:

```
public void save(News transientInstance) {
    log.debug("saving News instance");
    try {
        save(transientInstance);
        log.debug("save successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("save failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public void insert(NewsForm newsForm, RequestContext context) {
    NewsDAO NewsDAO = (NewsDAO) ApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("NewsDAO");


    News newNews = new News();
    Timestamp date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    newNews.setDate(date);
    newNews.setTitle(newsForm.getTitle());
    newNews.setDescription(newsForm.getDescription());
    newNews.setBody(newsForm.getBody());
    newNews.setStatus(newsForm.getStatus());
    newNews.setUpdateDate(date);
    NewsDAO.save(newNews);
}
```

Error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.debug(Log4JLogger.java:177)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68)
dao.NewsDAO.save(NewsDAO.java:68) ...etc
```

Is this DAO code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save method calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method, which calls the save method...

Replace `save(transientInstance)` by `hibernateTemplate.save(transientInstance)`.

(and please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lower-case letter).

Comment: +1 especially for this part : "...please respect the Java naming conventions..."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Endless recursion has stopped but it has still some error .